# Copy row with formulas and format then insert a new row in excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a C# application where I have an excel default template file where the first 10 rows are kind of fixed. Then the following row11 have some cells which are formulas and formats, and it's same for the row 12 and 13 where they have the same formulas and format except that they are automated filled using row 11 so for example if row11 col10 has a formula using row11 col9 cell then for row12 col10 will have the same formula except that it will be using row12 col9 and so on. So I wonder how I can add a row after row 13 where it will have the same formulas and format as the ones above and shifts the rest of rows downwards in the rest of the excel worksheet downwards. Below is how I opened the excel file:

```
Excel.Application myApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook my_workbook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\my Work\my_template.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet my_ws = my_workbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qe18tdlmuha4s6n/my_template.xlsx?dl=0) to the template file where I highlighted in red the two rows which I want to copy then insert downward, so what I would want to do is copy row 22 with it's format and formulas then insert it to be row 23 then copy row 37 with it's format and formulas then insert it to be row 38. Could you advise?

Comment: So it sound to me you want to copy a row with formulas, and then insert a row so it shifts rows downwards?

Comment: @Kevin exactly right, it's kind of copy a row which has formulas and format (such as merged cells etc.) then insert it downwards where the formaulas will be adjusted as if I did an expland fill.

Comment: If you showed an example of what you are trying to accomplish it might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just pseudo code, but maybe it will get you started, the formulas should automatically adjust based on the new row:

```
//insert new row at 23 (only do this if you want to shift product table down)
   my_ws.InsertRow(23);


    //Source Range
    Range sourceRange = my_ws.Cells.CreateRange(“A22:Z22”);
    
    //Destination range
    Range destRange = my_ws.Cells.CreateRange(“A23:Z23”);
    
    destRange.Copy(sourceRange);
```

Comment: Will this also copy the formatting? such as merged cells,...etc?

Comment: It should do the same thing when you copy and paste in Excel. Does that work?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qe18tdlmuha4s6n/my_template.xlsx?dl=0 Here is a link to the template file where I highlighted in red the two rows which I want to copy then insert downward, so what I would want to do is copy row 22 with it's format and formulas then insert it to be row 23 then copy row 37 with it's format and formulas then insert it to be row 38. Could you advise?

Comment: Do you want to shift the products table down, or are you just looking to copy/paste?

Comment: So when I copy a summary row I want to insert it and shift all other rows down (which means rows of the products tables as well). And when I copy a product row I want to insert it below and shift all the other rows down.

Comment: I cannot find the `InsertRow` or the `CreateRange` functions when I type `my_ws.` Not sure why?